# Directory path to recursive array with children relation

Tags: php, recursion

I want to explode a directory path into an recursive array with children but keep directories unique.

Let's say we have the following input:

```
$paths = [
    'parent/first child',
    'parent/second',
    'parent/second/with-another-children',
    'parent/third/another children',
    'parent/last children'
];

foreach($paths as $path){
    $folders = explode('/', $path);

    //$traverse($folders);
}
```

Expected output

```
[
    'directory_name' => 'parent',
    'children' => [
        [
            'directory_name' => 'first child',
            'children' => []
        ],
        [
            'directory_name' => 'second',
            'children' => [
                'directory_name' => 'with-another-children',
                'children' => []
            ]
        ],
        [
            'directory_name' => 'third',
            'children' => [
                'directory_name' => 'another children',
                'children' => []
            ]
        ],
        [
            'directory_name' => 'last children',
            'children' => []
        ],
    ]
];
```

I've got this array of paths from an HTML folder upload. I need to create directories first (in db not file system) and after that upload files (all in same folder) but keep directory id where the file should be shown. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a recursive function to build the structure, and if you use a keyed array it becomes much simpler to work with as you don't have to search arrays for entries with a certain `directory_name`:

```
$paths = [
    'parent/first child',
    'parent/second',
    'parent/second/with-another-children',
    'parent/third/another children',
    'parent/last children'
];

$out = [];

foreach($paths as $path) {
    $parts = explode('/', $path);
    $cur = &$out;
    foreach($parts as $part) {
        if(!key_exists($part, $cur)) {
            $cur[$part] = [ 'children' => []];
        }
        $cur = &$cur[$part]['children'];
    }
    unset($cur);
}

var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["parent"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["children"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["first child"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["second"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["children"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["with-another-children"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ["third"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["children"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["another children"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ["last children"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a recursive function, with this pattern :

- Look in the children of the root if the first directory exists. It not create it
- Then, append all the remaining directory to this child's children

I added a first empty element to represent the root, because I am not sure that all paths will begin per `parent`

Note the `&` to keep the modifications on the tree outside the function :

```
$tree = array('directory_name' => '' /* root */, 'children' => array());
foreach($paths as $path){
    $folders = explode('/', $path);

    addFoldersToTree($tree, $folders);
}
print_r($tree);


function addFoldersToTree(&$tree, $folders)
{
    if( count($folders) == 0 )
    {
        // no more path to add, end
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($tree['children'] as &$child) 
        {
            if($child['directory_name'] == $folders[0])
            {
                // first directory already exists, add the rest of the path to this child
                addFoldersToTree($child, array_slice($folders, 1));
                return ;
            }
        }

        // child doesnn't exists yet, create it ...
        $new_child = array(
            'directory_name' => $folders[0],
            'children' => array() 
        );
        addFoldersToTree($new_child, array_slice($folders, 1)); //... and append the rest of the path to it
        $tree['children'][] = $new_child ;
    }
}
```